# Can existing website users post in Facebook comment plugin?

Tags: facebook, facebook-comments

currently troubled on how (and whether) to integrate Facebook commenting plugin on my website.

Can you allow registered users to post on Facebook plugin? If not, is it best to only allow people to login with Facebook to use my website?

Any ideas? Thank you all in advance!

Answer (score 0):

The comments plugin will only work with users who are registered and logged into Facebook.  See: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/comments/

You can allow people to log into your website using this plugin:  https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/login/

Answer (score 0):

You would have to detet whether a user has a valid facebook session.
You can do that with the link that @DMCS posted. 
 If you detect that there is no valid facebook session- you could hide the facebook comments box, perhaps have a fallback of read-only comments that your application has pre-fretched.

Comment: Hi lix, thanks for the reply. So basically existing users (with no FB account) will not be able to post in the Facebook comment plugin? And its best the two types of comments are kept separate?<br><br>Is there a way to retrieve the Facebook comments on a specific post and display them in my websites comments? (i.e. merge them?) Thanks alot!